# How to Store dynamic table value using SharedPreference in android

Tags: android

I am developing web services based android application below i mentioned my application output....
here's my dynamic table view

```
final LinearLayout linear = new LinearLayout(
                                MainActivity.this);
                        MainLayout.setWeightSum(1.0f);
                        TableRow row1 = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
                        row1.setId(1000 + sCount);
                        text1 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                        text1.setText(button.getText());
                        text1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0,
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2f);
                        text1.setLayoutParams(params);

                        // text1.setGravity(100);
                        final Button button = new Button(MainActivity.this);
                        EditText e = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                        LayoutParams params1 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0,
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f);
                        e.setLayoutParams(params1);
                        e.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                        arryList.add(text1.getText().toString());
                        nameArray = arryList.toArray(new String[arryList
                                .size()]);
                        String itemname = text1.getText().toString();

                        button.setText(" X ");
                        button.setId(2000 + sCount);
                        LayoutParams params2 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0,
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f);
                        button.setLayoutParams(params2);
                        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                MainLayout.removeView(findViewById(v
                                        .getId() - 1000));
                            }
                        });

                        sCount++;
                        row1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                                TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        row1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                        row1.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
                        row1.addView(text1);
                        row1.addView(e);

                        row1.addView(button);
                        MainLayout.addView(row1);


                    }
                    ll.addView(MainLayout);
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

the output is

[image]

i want store the textview values and edittext values in sharedpreference...after that i want to retrieve the same value and load the same table layout...how can i do that??
please any help me...thanks in advance..

Comment: i used SavePreferences("MEM1", text1.getText().toString()); for store the value of text1....but it displays only last entered value..how can i solve it....i want display all text1 values....

Answer (score 2):

To save

```
 SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
            prefsEditor.putInt("VariableName", Value);
            prefsEditor.putInt("VariableName2", Value);
            prefsEditor.commit();
```

To read

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
int d = myprefs.getInt("VariableName", defaultvalue);
```

Comment: i used SavePreferences("MEM1", text1.getText().toString()); for store the value of text1....but it displays only last entered value..how can i solve it....i want display all text1 values....

Comment: put this "to save" code where value is changing in runtime or dynamically so that latest value will be in shared pref